# Exception : WCF service thrown Bad Request while saving image as byte array to Database

Tags: .net, wcf, exception

I have created a WCF service for saving an image as a byte array. below are the contract,implementation and enpoint details

**Contract**

```
  [OperationContract]
        void InsertEmployeeData(EmployeeDetail empName);
```

**Implementation**

```
 public void InsertEmployeeData(EmployeeDetail empName)
        {
            ctx.EmployeeDetails.AddObject(empName);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When i try to save below 15 kb i can save successfully.When uploading more than 15 kb i got exception **The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request** How can i resolve this error?

**Binding Details**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ImobService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxBufferSize="250000000" maxBufferPoolSize="250000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000"
            maxArrayLength="4500000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://anishk.india-powai.orioninc.com/mobservice/MobService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ImobService"
        contract="MobileService.ImobService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ImobService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Did you also configure the same binding configuration on the server? The client and server configuration should be the same.

Comment: Yes.I have configured both client and server

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the service on IIS, there is good change that the request length is limited to 15 kb. Try changing the IIS setting

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="25000" />
```

Change the request length to max. file size you want to upload.

Comment: Is the wcf service exposed directly, or you use it by consuming it in your web application?

Comment: Then,you need to change IIS setting on both the Web Application config and the service config.

Comment: How can i change these settings?

Comment: Go to IIS where your web applicaton and service are deployed and change the request length.. http://i47.tinypic.com/28bttn7.jpg